# db.out.ogr duplicates items and adds an empty one

Tags: grass-gis, csv

I export an attribute table of streams_order layer to CSV.
My attribute table in GRASS is ok:
[image: Here is an attribute table from GRASS GUI]
But my CSV file has all features duplicated and an odd 0 feature with no information:
[image: Here is my CSV table exported and opened in Excel]

What's wrong and why?

In terminal window I have warnings:

```
WARNING: The combination of types is not supported by all formats.
WARNING: No areas found, but requested to be exported. Will skip this
     feature type.
```

I don't know if it matters...

UPD: I think I know the cause. There are both points and lines in my vector layer. So, is there some possibility to tell db.out.ogr to export only lines table?

Here is v.info about my vector layer:

```
 Map format:      native                                              
 Type of map: vector (level: 2)                                            
 Number of points:       3451            
 Number of centroids:  0      
 Number of lines:        3450   
 Number of boundaries: 0   
 Number of areas:        0               
 Number of islands:    0    
 Map is 3D:              No                                               
 Number of dblinks:      1
```

Comment: You can try instead: `v.out.ogr` with the `type=line` parameter and `format=CSV`

Comment: Thank you, that worked!
Please, copy you comment to answer, otherwise I can't check it as an answer.